# Do we know the story behind this suit in the Batcave?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In Batman vs Superman, we see this suit in the Batcave:

[image]

Do we know the story behind it? As far as I know, it's never really explained in the film.

Comment: http://www.cinemablend.com/new/What-Happened-Robin-Pre-Batman-V-Superman-121757.html

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95413/is-this-scene-from-batman-v-superman-trailer-from-comics

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of the graffiti saying “Joke's on You Batman”?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/59593/49)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### This is Robin's costume

The suit has an "R" on it, for Robin. This is probably a sign that the Joker previously killed Robin.

[image]
The raised area (circled) is a script "R."

For the purposes of comparison, a similar costume from the comics:
[image]

As indicated [here](http://www.thegeektwins.com/2015/07/13-amazing-things-you-missed-in-batman.html#.V3uES7grJEY), there has previously been a comics storyline in which Robin died at the hands of the Joker.

> It's a reference to the 1988 comic "Batman: A Death in the Family"
> when the Joker kills Jason Todd,  the second Robin, in an
> explosion.There have been a bunch of Robin's but leaked set photos
> show a gravestone that says "Richard Grayson".

The creator has [also](http://screencrush.com/snyder-batman-superman-robin-history/) commented on this:

> In my mind, it was that Robin had died 10 years earlier, during some
> run in with a young Joker (Jared Leto). To me, it was a fun backstory
> there to play with. The whole idea was that there had been loss and
> sacrifice. In a weird way, he sacrificed everything to be Batman,
> right? He doesn’t really have a life outside of the cave. I thought by
> including Robin — a dead Robin — it would help us understand he’s been
> on quite a little journey.
>
> <sub><sup>Credit to sequoiad</sup></sub>

Comment: To add to this, this was said [during an interview with Snyder](http://screencrush.com/snyder-batman-superman-robin-history/) "In my mind, it was that Robin had died 10 years earlier, during some run in with a young Joker (Jared Leto). To me, it was a fun backstory there to play with. The whole idea was that there had been loss and sacrifice. In a weird way, he sacrificed everything to be Batman, right? He doesn’t really have a life outside of the cave. I thought by including Robin — a dead Robin — it would help us understand he’s been on quite a little journey."

Comment: “To me, it was a fun backstory there to play with.” — Super-fun!

Comment: I hope it's not Grayson

Comment: I think a better comparison image would be this one (or a similar one): https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/75/Robin0.JPG The shape of the letter R appears to be inspired by the Tim Drake-era costume (or a later one that took stylistic cues from Drake's R)

Comment: @AnkitSharma - nah, hopefully they stick with Jason Todd. The character was a jerk to begin with, which is why fans voted for him to die.

Answer (score 16):

[Affleck](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/03/09/batman-v-superman-ben-affleck-wonder-woman) confirmed that it was indeed Robin's costume, but that beyond that the backstory isn't terribly well fleshed out. It was simply to show that his past troubles him.

> **He had a Robin at one point, and we don’t know exactly which Robin that was, but we learned he died.**
>   He’s bitterly disappointed in the past that he’s lost this guy who fought by his side. That character’s death must have been devastating to him, and he’s suffered. We get the sense that he’s suffered a lot of devastating losses before this movie even starts.

Comment: To me it sounds like they are useing a variation of the Bronze Age Timeline with Batman's stuff shifted about 18 years. All the facts I've parsed from MoS, what I know of DC timelines, and BvS, seems to track with this idea. That is almost 100% certain to be Jason Todd's costume. The only thing that gives me pause is DC keeps mixing and matching Robins (Like for some reason Arkham Knight has tim in a relationship with Barbara Gordon *sigh*) and that suit has Tim's Bo-Staff so that's a bit concerning. Also it makes sense this would be Todd's due to it being so black indicating its been burnt.

Comment: @Durakken I think expecting details like this to remain consistent across reboots is like expecting the same football team to remain champion year after year. It happens in some settings, but in most settings, authors want to wash away the damage done by less popular authors or even make their own controversial changes to canon (like the recent Captain America arc).

Comment: What you said is like saying that there should be no expectation of a story remain consistent. That is patently the exact opposite of what a story is. There are minor changes one could expect, but not such large and sweeping changes that change important character details, such as the Death of Jason Todd, Dick having a relationship with Barbara, and the motivation for how Tim became Robin.

Comment: There isn't any expectation of consistency. It's a mythos comprised of many stories from many storytellers, that can (and probably should) contradict each other. You can argue that the storytellers should at least maintain internal consistency within their stories, but even that's entirely up to the stoyteller. Switching up some details of a story to approach it from a different angle can be very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

It was Jason Todd's suit. It's a sad detail for comic readers. Jason was killed by the Joker in the 1988 comic 'A death in the family' and Batman kept his suit as a reminder for how he failed to save Jason, which he sees as his greatest failure ever. Jason did get revived and came back as Red Hood.

Comment: The Joker killed Jason Todd in the comics, but has it been confirmed that the same thing happened in the DCEU, and that the suit shown in the question was Jason's? It isn't safe to assume that what's true in the comics is also true in the movies.